# Postgres max on few columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, aggregate-functions

I have table, which looks like this

```
 id | item | price1 | price2
```

I want do get the list of items and for every item I want also to select max price among price1 and price2. Is it possible to do that in one query? Something like

```
SELECT item, max(price1,price2) FROM table;
```

**UPDATE**

Example:

table contains

```
item1 | 4 | 8
item2 | 5 | 1
item3 | 7 | 7
```

I want result to be

```
item1 | 8
item2 | 5
item3 | 7
```

Comment: Can you show what an example of what you expect the result to look like?

Comment: use max(price1), max(price2) a group by and a case statement to select the larger of the two as your the final output signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GREATEST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) :

```
SELECT GREATEST(1, 100);
┌──────────┐
│ greatest │
├──────────┤
│      100 │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```